# Docker LEMP stack with WordPress, what needs to connect to memcached?

Tags: php, postgresql, docker, nginx, memcached

I'm trying to wrap my head around Docker and containerisation.
To help myself I've whipped up a little relation diagram for all the separate programs (containers).

One question that keeps cropping up is which of the programs needs to interface with Memcached? In my head I'm thinking that WordPress, nginx, postgresql and php-fpm all need to interface with Memcached.

Is this correct or do only nginx and/or php-fpm and/or postgresql need to interface with memcached?

[Container relations digram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etkJB.jpg)